# Create an Error object with particular properties in unit testings

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to implement unit test for the following piece of my code

```
try {
   return await request.post(options);
} catch (err) {
   if (err.statusCode === 401) {
     log.info('Not authenticated. Refreshing token...');
     const tokenResponse =
              await Janus.refreshToken(graph.username, graph.password, graph.host, graph.port);
     const token = tokenResponse.body.token;
     graph.token = token;
     return gremlinQuery(graph, query);
   }
   log.error(`Gremlin script didn't pass : ${err}`);
 }
```

In order to test the lines contained in the `catch` part, I stub the `post` function:

```
stubPost.callsFake(() => Promise.reject(new Error()));
```

How can I implement an error with the property `statusCode`? `Error` constructor is waiting for a `string` as an input. Can't I pass it an object or something like that?

Comment: There is a great example on MDN for creating a custom Error. I would suggest that route. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: You dont have to throw error object. Reject itself should result in catch block. You can pass plain old `{}` in reject()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this could be as below

```
MyApiError = function(data) {
  this.code = data.code; 
  this.message = data.message
}
MyApiError.prototype = Error.prototype;

var e = new MyApiError({code: 33, message: 'test'});

e.code; // 33
e.message; // 'test'
```